# New-fangled "view statistics" not working on upgraded CruiseControl.NET server

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net, upgrade

Recently I upgraded a couple of CruiseControl.NET server from version 1.3 to version 1.4.2.14.  After the upgrade I was pleased to note that the "View Statistics" link from the project's web dashboard sported a new view:

[image]

However,

I was quite disappointed to discover that another server that I upgraded in an identical way sported the old-style statistics page:

[image]

It seems that there is some configuration setting that didn't get enabled when I upgraded the second server.  Any ideas what controls this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the web dashboard and install again seemed to solve this issue.  I followed these steps:

1. Stop the WWW service
2. Go to the CC.NET installation directory and delete the webdashboard folder
3. Re-install CC.NET
4. Restart CCService and WWW service